# Identity specification

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

I have a problem with identity specification when I create a table in SQL Server 2016.

- In column Id I set Identity Increment and Identity Seed equal 1.
- Next I add  new  record  to new  table.
- In column Id show up 2 value. Why? Why not 1 value?
- Next drop the first record and add new. In column Id show up 3 value. Why? Why not 1 value.
- Next I use command ' update nametable  set id=1' and receive answer cannot update identity column Id. Why?

Comment: Why bother? ID values have no meaning, but shouldn't be reused.

Comment: The reason why you get a new value every time, why old values are never re-used and why you cannot alter the ID, is simply because the other values were already used previously. the ID must uniquely identify a specific row **forever**. Otherwise it could cause confusion, break foreign key relationships and generally make it difficult to understand which record is which.

Comment: For example, let's say you have an "images" table, and record 1 stores a filename, and a description "picture of cats". Record 2 is a filename and the description "picture of dogs. You display them on a web page, and people can bookmark their favourite images - the bookmarks are linked to the unique ID, logically. Now let's say you delete image 1. It's gone, people's bookmarks don't work any more, but you just give them a "sorry, bad luck" message.

Comment: ...But if you then add a new record called "picture of worms"...if ID 1 can be re-used for this, then all those who bookmarked ID 1 are going to visit the site and see something they didn't expect, and be confused. That's a trivial example of course, but hopefully you can see the more serious implications if the table was, for example "customers", or "employees", or "bank accounts"

Answer (score 2):

This is probably easier to explain with some code:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                        SomeCol varchar(5));

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SomeCol)
VALUES('abc'); --Will get ID 1

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SomeCol)
VALUES('def'),('ghi'); --Will get 2 and 3.

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;

DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable;

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SomeCol)
VALUES('abc'); --Will get ID 4, because 1-3 have been used. Deleting doesn't let you reuse values.

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;

DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable;

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.YourTable', RESEED, 1);

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SomeCol)
VALUES('abc'); --Will get ID 2, as you seeded back to 1; so the NEXT ID is used.

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable; 

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.YourTable;

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SomeCol)
VALUES('abc'); --Will get ID 4, because 1-3 have been used.

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable; --Will get ID 1, as the column was reseed with the TRUNCATE


DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

For your specific question on reseeding, the next value after the seed your define is use. The seed you define is the one you are saying was last used. This is covered in the documentation [Forcing the current identity value to a new value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-forcing-the-current-identity-value-to-a-new-value):

> Because the table has existing rows, the next row inserted will use 11
>   as the value – the new current identity value defined for the column
>   plus 1 (which is the column's increment value).

The only way to define a table doesn't have existing rows is the `TRUNCATE` it, which is what I do later on in the above batch (and why 1 is reused).

At the end of the day, the value of your `IDENTITY` is meaningless other than to provide the row with a single use value (which is not guarenteed to be unique on it's own). Combined with the Primary key/Unique constraints, it makes a good Clustered index candidate, as the next value is always greater than the last used, and values aren't reused.

If having sequential values is important, then what you need to use is a `SEQUENCE`, not the `IDENTITY` property. The latter doesn't guarantee uniqueness, or sequential values on it's own (as they could be skipped due to deletes, failed inserts, an unexpected shutdown, etc), but it does guarantee it will not reuse values once they have been (without a `RESEED`): [IDENTITY (Transact-SQL) - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017#remarks). A `SEQUENCE` can be used to ensure the values are indeed sequential (apart from due to a `DELETE`).

Comment: You could also reset the identity to 0 using DBCC CHECKIDENT. The next identity value will be 1 then. (Except when using DBCC CHECKIDENT with seed value 0 on a table that never had any records since creation, in which case the next identity value will be 0...)

Comment: But I agree with you that the value of IDENTITY columns should be meaningless except for providing a unique value. :)

Comment: I'd copy and pasted my comments and not, editted, sorry,

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the forum :)

If you created the table using

```
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Then the first record inserted will have Id = 1, however, if the insert statement fails or the transaction is rolled back the consumed identity be marked as used (or lost) and the next insert statement will proceed from Id = 2.

Have a look at Microsoft documentation on this topic:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

When deleting inserted rows (which also happens when those inserts are rolled-back in a transaction, by the way), the identity value is not automatically reset. The identity functionality "remembers" its last value.

Gaps in the identity values will also NOT be filled when older records are deleted from the table and new records are inserted into the table.

That's just how identity works. It's a simple and safe mechanism.

If you (occasionally!) want to reset the identity value, you can take a look at [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql). I personally tend to use it like this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED, 0) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
```

(I execute both lines, in this order.)

I would advice against this practice in production environments, however.